# Python check for NoneType not working

Tags: python, if-statement, nonetype

I'm trying to check whether an object has a None type before checking it's length. For this, I've done an if statement with an or operator:

```
if (cts is None) | (len(cts) == 0):
return
```

As far as I can tell, the object `cts` will be checked if it's None, and if it is, the length check won't run. However, the following error happens if `cts` is None:

`TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

Does python check both expressions in an if statement, even if the first is true?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Python, `|` is a [bitwise or](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/bitwise.html).  You want to use a [logical or](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/boolean.html) here:

```
if (cts is None) or (len(cts) == 0):
    return
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference - I thought they were interchangeable

Comment: Thanks so much! Was having problems with my Mako template, was trying `%if 'member' is None:` but your solution fixed it :)

Answer (score 18):

You can also use -

```
if not cts: return
```

Comment: Would that check whether the list is empty too?